# Error storing datetime in a variable

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datetime, casting

I want to store the datetime in a variable but it gives me an error.  I am using SQL-Server 2005 and vb.net.

```
SQL.SQLDataSet.Tables(0).Rows.Item("fin_year").ToString
```

The error is `invalid casting from string to int`

Comment: Your current code reads, it doesn't store anything. Care to add a few precisions, show the exception's stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

The SqlServer datetime field is not an int, you can either return the whole datetime and store it in a VB Date variable and use VB functions to get the year, or you can use the sql function  YEAR() on the datetime field in the select statement and return the year as an integer